# Drupal 7 - getting list of pages with number of hits and created date

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal, I have a site of version 7.12 that I need to make changes to. A complete relaunch. For that I need to provide a list of all the content type pages that are frequently searched and pages that never got hit so that I can remove them. Is there a way to see that list?

Answer (score 0):

You needed to have the statistics module turned on for drupal to track this information. You can see how to turn it on here:

https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics

Another possible solution is if you had google analytics setup on your site you could see all that information.